# Securing S3 bucket for users?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have developed a react native app, with AWS Amplify to support the backend (DynamoDB, S3). All users of the app have to use Auth.signIn() to sign in and are part of a user pool.

Once in, they can start to upload videos to S3 via the app or view videos in the app that are in the S3 bucket that is **PUBLIC**.

I use the path to the S3 video (https://myS3bucket....) as the source URL of the video. However the videos are only visible in my app when the bucket is public. Any other setting (protected/private) and no video is visible. How can i make this more secure?

Comment: The bucket doesn't need to be public. You can have public files in a private bucket and that should still work. However if you want to protect files to ensure only certain users can see them you will need your server to act as a proxy to the files instead of offering direct S3 access to them.

Comment: yes. You need to create `Pre-Signed URLs` for the files which will grant a temporary url that will be valid for the time you specify. That should help you i guess.

Comment: @Panther The URL's need to be visibile indefinitely. The videos in the S3 bucket need to be available at all times for users of the app to see

Comment: I hope you are restricting the video files to be accessed only by the users who have signed in. In that case having an open url will lead to anyone getting the access without the need for your app. Thee best way is to protect it and generate as you require. You can also do the ACLs on object level, but  not recommended.

Comment: @Panther Precisely. Right now anyone can access that URL. I need to restrict access to only users logged in (via Auth.signIn() or in my user pool). Thats what i need help on.

Comment: you should generate a signed url and store it somewhere and re-generate it in every n minutes you choose or when ever a user access the videos, see if you have a valid url and send it right away, or generate a new one and store it and send that..

Answer (score 1):

S3 Buckets have 3 methods of managing security:

- IAM: Any user or role within the same AWS account as the bucket can be granted permissions to interact with the S3 Bucket and its objects.
- [S3 Bucket Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html): Grant bucket wide (or prefix) access to S3 buckets.
- [S3 ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html) - Per object level permissions.

Its generally advised against using S3 ACLs these days as their functionality was improved via S3 bucket policies. Only use them if you need a specific object to have a different set of permissions.

Comment: Currently i am the only IAM user (administrator). But it do have a Cognito user pool with all the users of the app in it. They have been authenticated to sign in (via Cognito), and its this user pool of users that need to be able to upload and view the videos in S3. How can i have them do this, and stop my Bucket from being Public so anyone can access the URL's to the videos?

Comment: Hi, your users can have an IAM role bound to them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html. When they login you'll get access to some temporary credentials that can be fed into the SDK. Give this role the permissions required.

Answer (score 0):

I sugeest not to make files or the bucket public if you want authenticated users to upload and/or download files. For this, use [S3 signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) to give users access to files. In other words, the backend will authenticate users accordingly, generate them signed URLs and then the react native app will interpret that URL accordingly, ie a video file.

You will need to change a few things but [this guide](https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/securing-aws-s3-uploads-using-presigned-urls-aa821c13ae8d) should cover that

Comment: Hi Vitalij, will the signed URL's expire? I need the URL's to these video to always be available for all users of the app. Right now, all users of my app are in a Cognito user pool.

Comment: Yes, pre-signed URLs expire. But you don't want or need long-lived credentials.

Comment: @jarmod is right, generate them for a short period of time, say 2 hours. Enough for for people to share it over WhatsApp and more than enough to give permissions to the requester. If you don't plan on third party sharing 20 minutes should be ok as well, just make sure you generate a new signed URL everytime, it will make you life easier

Answer (score 0):

I have recently published an article which describes in detail the security best practices, which help address the following points:

- How to secure an S3 buckets, which store sensitive user data and the application code.
- How to securely configure a CloudFront distribution.
- How to protect frontend apps against common OWASP threats with CloudFront Functions.

To learn more [have a look at the article](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-you-need-to-know-to-secure-apps-with-cloudfront-functions-and-s3-d9f5c966d8a9).

Best,
Stefan